# Design Pattern for Installed module based application

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Can someone point me in the  right direction as to what sort of design patterns I should be looking at.

There is a base application, and we may have more than one business module developed. Each module is developed independently, and there is a requirement to merge these modules into one application. The modules may also need to interact with each other.

So there can be several combinations, and maintaining each combination is just not possible in the long term.

I have identified the interaction between modules, and was thinking of separating them using abstract classes. Which means that when I do merge 2 modules, I just need to copy the derived classes across, and they should just work. Is there a name for such a design pattern?

Are there other design patterns which could benefit me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.

**Plugin system:**

1. Create an `IApplicationHost` interface which defines a set of base methods (like a `Resolve` and `Register` methods a la inversion of control / dependency injection).
2. Create a `IPlugin` interface which has a `Setup(IApplicationHost host)` method. Each plugin use it to setup the plugin.
3. Add a `Start` method to `IPlugin` too.

3) is needed since plugins can be dependent of each other. You first call `Setup` for each plugin to let them register their interface implementations etc. Next thing to do is to traverse all plugins again to call `Start` method for each.

All plugins are loaded by using `Assembly.Load`. Simply name all plugins like `plugin_XXXX.dll` to be able to identify them easily.

**Plugin architecture**

Since plugins can be use each other you need some way to support that. The easiest way is to use the Separated Interface pattern which means that you place all domain objects and service interfaces in a separate assembly. This also makes it far easier to keep backwards compability when releasing new versions of plugins. Simply never change the interfaces, extend them instead.

Then create a class library for the actual plugin. It should be dependent of it's own interface assembly, the applications assembly and all specification assemblies of the plugins that it's dependent of.

Comment: Since Axapta dosent really support DLL's and this is more of either the module exists or not, so its not as complex as a plugin. There can only be one module, if the module dosent exist then the developer can go and remove the code from the connector class which return false or null which can be handled in the main application. Yes there will be an upgrade to the application everytime when modules are merged but that is an acceptable cost.

Comment: I have access to checking if a class exists using the class name as a string. SO i have an abstract class, and a non-implemented derived class (which will be returned if the module hasnt been merged into the application). I guess its a very crude was of implementing the Plugin system, except there can be only one plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/plugin.html) will allow a host application to dynamically load functionality (conforming to an interface) in seperate modules.

If you are developing for windows in .NET winforms, suggest you look at the [Smart Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648753.aspx)

Comment: Is there something which could be more specific, and not be dynamic?
Every module can be stripped down to have an interface, and only if the module is loaded should it go and implement the functionality. Unfortunately this is not .Net Dyanamics Ax, (formerly known as Axapta) is what I am working on

Comment: Can i apply any non dynamic design pattern?
This is probably separating code so that there is a least amount of change in the main application code.